# How to define multiple paths in java.library.path on tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat7

how can you define multiple paths e.g.

1. C:\tomcat\jnilib
2. d:\bar

as value to the java.library.path option on a tomcat 7 server.

I am working on windows so I guessed this should work

```
-Djava.library.path=c:\tomcat\jnilib;d:\bar
```

But my webapplication in the tomcat server does not find the necessary dlls which are in the folder d:\bar. If I place the them into the jnilib folder and remove the second path in the java.library.path then the webapp finds the dlls.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30176215/multiple-directories-in-djava-library-path for Linux solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if that will solve your problem, but I've seen examples where it was formatted with double quotes and spaces between entries, e.g.:

```
-Djava.library.path="c:\tomcat\jnilib; d:\bar"
```