# Multiple directories in -Djava.library.path

Tags: java, jvm, java-native-interface, jvm-arguments, java.library.path

How can I point to two differents `java.library.path` in eclipse project - run configurations? I need these two libraries:

```
-Djava.library.path=/opt/hdf-java/build/bin
-Djava.library.path=/opt/opencv-2.4.10/build/lib
```

Regards.

Answer (score 55):

On Linux, use colon `:` as separator (as you will do with the classpath option) as in:

```
-Djava.library.path=/opt/hdf-java/build/bin:/opt/opencv-2.4.10/build/lib
```

Comment: On windows, use semicolon `;`

Answer (score 17):

Use the platform's `File.pathSeparator`, i.e. `;` on Windows and `:` on *nix, to separate directories, just like you would separate the directories in the classpath.

e.g. `Windows`:

```
-Djava.library.path=C:/dir1;C:/dir2
```

or `*nix`:

```
-Djava.library.path=/dir1:/dir2
```