# How to add multiple path locations in java.library.path in IntelliJIdea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jvm, virtual-machine

I am trying to specify java.library.path via VM options in IntelliJ Idea but not sure how to specify multiple paths

I am adding like below
-Djava.library.path=c:/loc1:c:/loc2 but it doesn't seem to work. I don't think i can use semi-colon as its for entering another variable.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What operating system? You have to use the [`File.pathSeparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#pathSeparatorChar) - which depends on your platform.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn : I am in Windows 10. I am using IntelliJ Idea editor. Want to know the exact syntax for the example  i mentioned in OP. I Can't use the semi colon as it doesn't work.

Comment: On Windows it should be semicolon https://stackoverflow.com/a/52827526/12844632 . Where exactly do you specify java.library.path? Try to specify it in the Run/Debug configuration | VM Options field.